# Is the Fujiwara bound the most precise bound on maximum absolute value of complex roots of real polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Is the Fujiwara bound the most precise bound on maximum absolute value of complex roots of real polynomials ? Or does it exist some improved version for this special case of real polynomials ?

Answer (score 1):

[This wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots#Other_bounds) discusses some of the improvements of the Fujiwara bound.

If the coefficients of your polynomial are all positive then the Eneström-Kakeya bound is often very good.  See, for example, [this paper](http://www.math.kent.edu/~varga/pub/paper_116.pdf) (PDF).  There are some generalizations, for instance when the coefficients lie in a given sector symmetric about the positive real axis.